# kik.send inside a iframe fails on ios even when kik.js loaded

Tags: kik

`kik.send` inside a `iframe` fails on iOS even when kik.js is loaded but works on android correctly.

**Included kik.js**

```
<script src="http://cdn.kik.com/kik/1.0.9/kik.js"></script>
```

**Code snippet:**

```
$('#kik_it').click(function(){
            kik.send({
         title     : 'Top Offers',
            text      : $('.description').html().trim(),
            pic       : $('.coupon_big_image').find('img').attr('src'),
        data      : {dealid : window.location.href}
    });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a known limitation in the Kik browser on iOS. The best workaround is to either remove the need for iframes (usually a good idea anyway) or to have the iframe reach up into the parent window and send the message from there.